# Hibernate debug/trace logging when both logback and log4j are in classpath

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, apache-poi, log4j2, logback

Having:

- `Spring-boot:2.6.7`
- `Hibernate:5.6.8`
- `logback` as default logging implementation
- Apache POI `poi-ooxml:5.2.3`.

We need to log SQL queries and parameters. Usually this is enabled either from Spring logging configuration:

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=trace
```

or directly in `logback.xml` configuration:

```
<logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="debug"/>
<logger name="org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql" level="trace"/>
```

Both were working until recent POI update. Starting from [POI 5.1.0 it requires `log4j2` API](https://poi.apache.org/components/logging.html) and can not be excluded from classpath any more (otherwise `XSSFWorkbook` can't be initialized at runtime).

This leads that both `logback` and `log4j2` API classes are in classpath.

At the same time Hibernate uses JBoss Logger provider ([BasicExtractor](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.6.8/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/type/descriptor/sql/BasicExtractor.java#L27), [BasicBinder](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.6.8/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/type/descriptor/sql/BasicBinder.java#L27)) which has `log4j2` [precedence](https://github.com/jboss-logging/jboss-logging/blob/3.4.3.Final/src/main/java/org/jboss/logging/LoggerProviders.java#L85-L97).

Without `log4j` it works fine and [prints SQL and and parameters](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.6.8/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/type/descriptor/sql/BasicBinder.java#L51), but as soon as `log4j2` available, either Spring or `logback.xml` configurations are ignored and debug or traces are not printed any more.

I tried the following:

- excluding log4j API from POI: leads to runtime exception as `org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger` is not available in `XSSFWorkbook`
- including `org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j2-impl:2.20.0` and `org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:2.20.0`: doesn't help (logger provider is still `Log4j2LoggerProvider` and the Logger implementation ignores Spring or logback configuration
- including `org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:2.0.9` - doesn't work either

**Question**: is it possible to configure the application to enable debug and trace for Hibernate classes if both logback and slf4j2 are in classpath?

(without having both `logback.xml` and `log4j2.xml` files in the classpath)

Comment: Adding `log4j-to-slf4j` (from log4j2 not from slf4j) should do the trick as in the end it should all be routed to SLF4J and thus logback.

Comment: As i wrote in the post - i tried it: "including log4j-slf4j2-impl or/and log4j-to-slf4j: doesn't help (logger provider is still Log4j2LoggerProvider and the Logger implementation ignores Spring or logback configuration". Yes, it prints the default info logs, but debug|trace for 'org.hibernate.*' are ignored, unless specified in log4j2.xml

Comment: Did you include the proper `log4j-to-slf4j` uou should include the one from the Log4j project **not** from SLF4J. ALso adding the impl will not help. You should only have the API and the adapter for SLF4J.

Comment: specifically i tried `org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:2.20.0` and `org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j2-impl`. I haven't found any other `log4j-to-slf4j` implementation. Guess you mean `org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j`? (which i also tried and it didn't work either)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Spring Boot's starters you have nothing to do: every starter pulls in [`spring-boot-starter`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter), which depends on [`spring-boot-starter-logging`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-logging). The latter depends on:

- [`logback-classic`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic),
- the right bridges between every major logging API and SLF4J (which is Logback's native API). Among them you have [`log4j-to-slf4j`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-to-slf4j), which connects the Log4j API to SLF4J.

Just remove all explicit logging dependencies and exclusions and you should be fine. You should especially remove [`log4j-slf4j2-impl`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-slf4j2-impl): its naming is ambiguous, but it is actually a bridge from SLF4J to the Log4j API. If you deploy it together with `log4j-to-slf4j` it will issue a warning and deactivate itself to prevent an infinite recursion.

**Remark**: Spring's version of JCL (cf. [source code](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-to-slf4j)) also prefers the Log4j API over SLF4J.

**Edit**: Might I provide some debugging tips:

- `XSSFWorkbook` fails in your experiments if you forcibly exclude `log4j-api`. There is **no** need to do this. The `log4j-api/log4j-core` artifact pair works exactly as the `slf4j-api/logback-classic` pair: `log4j-api` and `slf4j-api` are APIs and they can be present at the same time, while `log4j-core` and `logback-classic` are their reference implementations and you want to replace one of them with a bridge to the other API,
- to check if you don't have multiple Log4j API implementations on your classpath, set `-Dlog4j2.debug=true` and look at the standard error of the application,
- to check if you don't have multiple SLF4J implementations, check the standard error.

Comment: I tried, this doesn't work: 1) "Among them you have log4j-to-slf4j, which connects the Log4j API to SLF4J." - yes, it connects and makes logging, but the logging level configured in `logback.xml`  or `application.properties` is ignored, thus no debug and trace for Hibernate (see BasicExtractor, BasicBinder logger); 2) without "log4j-slf4j2-impl" (it's not a bridge, but and implementation) the POI's `XSSFWorkbook` will crash at runtime

Comment: I edited my answer with some tips on debugging. When talking about `log4j-api` and `slf4j-api` it is better not to use the word "implementation": `log4j-to-slf4j` and `log4j-slf4j2-impl` are **both** implementations, but of different APIs. The former is a Log4j API implementation, the latter an SLF4J implementation. You want the former to replace the reference implementation `log4j-core`.

Comment: yes, you are right. At the end it appeared i messed smth with the included log4j implementation. If i include _only_ `log4j-to-slf4j` adapter without implementation - all works fine, and logging levels from Spring boot properties or `logback.xml` are applied.  This is also mentioned here: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.2/log4j-to-slf4j/index.html (Use of the SLF4J adapter (log4j-to-slf4j-2.0.jar) together with the SLF4J bridge (log4j-slf4j-impl-2.0.jar) should never be attempted)